# What is the probability that no two consecutive boxes have blue balls.?

Tags: probability

> There are red and blue balls which can be filled in 5 boxes.All balls are similar except color. what is the probability that no two consecutive boxes have blue balls.

Assume:A ball can be either red or blue with equal probability

```
Approach:

I could find only the no of ways for favourable cases.
```

Let we hv chose only ...1 B and 4 R balls...., So possible combinations are-

(B,R,R,R,R), (R,B,R,R,R), (R,R,B,R,R), (R,R,R,B,R), (R,R,R,R,B). => 5ways

Now assume we hv choose ....2 B and 3 R balls.., So possible combinations are-

(B,R,B,R,R), (B,R,R,B,R), (B,R,R,R,B), (R,B,R,B,R), (R,B,R,R,B), (R,R,B,R,B) => 6ways

similarly for 3 Blue balls, we hv only 1 option

(B, R, B, R, B)...........................................................................................=> 1 ways

we cant select 4 and 5 blue balls bcoz in these case we found 2 blue balls 
at consecutive place!!

Total 5+6+1= 12 Ans.

what are the no of  possible outcomes i was confused here.

Is it correct approach correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: You need to know how many Balls of each collor there are, or what is the probability of having say $3$ Blue and $2 $ red balls.

Comment: @ConradoCosta Yes i agree with you i have taken only a base case.Can it be solved?

Comment: Assume there are only red balls, the answer is 0 assume there are only blue balls, the answer is 1. So we need a probability distribution for the collors. You could say that you a ball can be either red or blue with equal probability. Then it can be solved. But you need to modify the question.

Comment: Can there be more than one red ball or more than one blue ball in a box ?

Comment: @ConradoCosta u are right.I edited the post.

Comment: @calculus yes but remember it should not be consecutive.

Comment: The rules are not completely clear. In your counting all boxes had exactly one ball, but in answering a comment you admitted more than one ball in the same box. How many balls are "filled" into the five boxes in all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume red balls and blue balls are equaly likelly. then each configuration

$$ B R B R B $$
Has probability $\frac{1}{32}$.

Now we have to count how many have not two consecutive blue balls.

you counted it. 12. But maybe you forgot the case when there are no blue balls. So I counted 13. In this case the probability is
$$\frac{13}{32} $$

Comment: But the Ans is 9/32

Comment: Maybe we counted it wrong. But maybe we need to think in the lines @calculus is suggesting what happens if you can put more than one ball in the box? We need to know how you choose a box to put the ball on. Is the box chosen with equal probability?

Comment: Yes the box choose with equal probability

Comment: @Jack  If the question means that one ball can be placed in each box and that it is equally likely that a red or blue ball can be placed in each box, then Conrado's answer is correct, as you can check by simply listing the $32$ cases.

Comment: @Jack I concur with N.F. Taussig. As explained, Conrado's answer is correct. I even did a little simulation to verify (not that we really need it for such a simple problem).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Conrado Costa is correct. I ran the following simulation in R:

```
for (i in 1:100000){ 
  B<-rbinom(5,1,.5)
  Z<-(B[1:4]==B[2:5])*(B[2:5]==1)
  if(i==1) S=0
  S=S+(sum(Z*1)>0)
}
```

I get $\frac{S}{1E5} = 0.59 \implies $ no consecutive blue box probability is $1-0.59 = 0.41 \approx \frac{13}{32}$

It's hard to see how you can only have nine favorable outcomes. Each of yours are valid, so we know that 12 is a lower bound, at least.